# Mono compatible CMS for Linux

Tags: asp.net, linux, content-management-system, mono

I'm looking for a CMS running under Mono framework: this is needed to have it deployed on Linux-based (Ubuntu/Debian) machines.

Someone told me about **OrchardCMS**, but it seems it's not compatible yet.
They also told me about **Umbarco**, but I haven't found any information on compatibility.

Could anyone advise?

Comment: Umbraco is ASP.NET on .NET servers. Dont think its MONO compatible.

Comment: I am currently investigating how to get MONO and ASP.NET up and running on Linux, as I am going to develop a MONO compatible CMS if possible. I've been doing CMS for 9 years now on Microsoft platform.

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at [mojoPortal](http://www.mojoportal.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Orchard is now Mono compatible see [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Running-Orchard-on-Mono) for details on setting up your system

Comment: The page says it is not compatabile

Comment: "Orchard doesn't currently run on Mono, and hence can't run on Linux." BUT on the same page mono setup guide is available. So maybe we need to ask people who really did that. And as I can understand MySQL is not supported. Only PostgreSQL with some issues - "After a few requests you might get npgsql (PostgreSQL ADO.NET provider) connection errors. Only restarting the application will cure it."